# Add a scale a coordinates in a Map

Tags: r, coordinates, scale

I am trying to add a scale and the coordinates to a map with the next RStudio code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(ggspatial)

ged <- read_csv("GEDEvent_v23_0_11.csv")

ged_confl <- ged |> 
filter(country == "DR Congo (Zaire)")
pal_num <- colorNumeric(palette = "inferno", 
domain = ged_confl$best, 
reverse = TRUE)

ged_confl |> 
leaflet() |> 
addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Voyager) |> 
addCircleMarkers(lng = ~longitude, 
lat = ~latitude,
popup = ~best,                   
color = ~pal_num(best),
label = ~best) |> 
addLegend(pal = pal_num, 
values = c(min(ged_confl$best):max(ged_confl$best)), 
position = "bottomright", 
title = "Nº de bajas estimadas", 
opacity = 0.8) 

ggplot(data=ged, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude)) +
geom_sf() + 
annotation_scale() + 
coord_sf()
```

But, I just get the map without the scale and the coordinates.

[image: this is what I get]

[image: That is the content of "ged"]

Isn´t the latitude and longitude what I should use in ggplot??

Comment: With `geom_sf`, the aesthetic to use is actually (IIUC) `geometry=` of an `"sf"` object, you need to convert the data at some point with `sf::st_as_sf` or just `sf::st_sf`, depending on a few things. One reason it may not be `lat`/`lon` is that some transformations (e.g., using `sf::st_transform(..)`) take it out of the lat/lon realm and into a cartesian projection.

Comment: See https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/ for good discussions about starting with `sf` in R. (If I've misread your needs here, my apologies.)

Comment: From the question, one might assume that you didn't actually execute the `ggplot()` -- screenshot only shows a Leaflet map and when using `geom_sf()` like this, you should receive an error about missing geometry aesthetics.  Though, you can use `ggspatial::annotation_scale()` without going through `sf` object (and `geom_sf()` ) , if needed.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77437044/add-scalebar-and-north-arrow-in-a-ggmap-without-using-ggsn

Comment: It might be easier to help if you add to your OP the data contained in `ged` or part of it with `dput(ged)`.